# Reusing function types in flow (static type checker)

Tags: javascript, flowtype

If I directly write functions like that, it works

```
declare module.exports: {
    // HTML tags
    div<Props>(...styles: Array<CSSStyles<Props>>): GlamorousComponent<Props>,
    section<Props>(...styles: Array<CSSStyles<Props>>): GlamorousComponent<Props>,
};
```

But to follow DRY, How do I separate a common type?
I tried:

```
declare type StyleFunction<Props> = (...styles: Array<CSSStyles<Props>>) => GlamorousComponent<Props>
declare module.exports: {
    // HTML tags
    div: StyleFunction<*>
};
```

But this doesn't typecheck at all.